# Backbone submit form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am having few problems with Backbone validation but it seems like I have found the right way. I have managed to achieve the following:

```
var EditUser = Backbone.View.extend({
el:'.page',
validates:function(evt){
    console.log('here');
    var $field = $(evt.currentTarget);
    if($field.val() === ''){
        $field.css('border', '1px solid red');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $field.css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
    }
},
render: function(options){
    var that = this;
    if(options.id){
        that.user = new User({id: options.id});
        that.user.fetch({
            success: function(user){
                var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html(), {user:user});
                that.$el.html(template);
            }
        });
    } else{
        var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html(), {user:null});
        this.$el.html(template);
    }
},
events: {
    'keyup input[name=firstname], input[name=lastname], input[name=age]': 'validates',
    'submit .edit-user-form': 'saveUser',
    'click .delete': 'deleteUser'
},
saveUser: function (ev){
    this.$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
        $(this).trigger('keyup');
    }); 
    var userDeatils = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
    var user = new User({validate:true});
    user.save(userDeatils,{
        success: function(user){
            router.navigate('', {trigger:true});
        }
    })
    return false;
},
deleteUser: function(ev){
    this.user.destroy({
        success: function(){
            router.navigate('', {trigger:true});
        }
    });
    return false;
}
});
```

Everything works fine when I start typing in the input fields, however I need the same action to happen when I submit the form. (which already has a saveUser attached). I need to find a way of running the validation ant stopping the form to be submitted with empty details before "saveUser" is called

Comment: have you considered implementing a `validate` function for User model and calling `user.isValid` in `saveUser`?

Comment: yes but unfortunately it doesn't work....

Comment: what you mean by "it doesn't work", could you give us an example of what you've tried?

Comment: In your saveUser function, inside the each statement, what happens if you try 
return $(this).trigger('keyup'); //added the return keyword

Answer (score 1):

Change `validates` like below.

```
validates:function(evt, $field){
    var valid = true;

    if(evt)
        $field = $(evt.currentTarget);

    if($field.val() === ''){
        $field.css('border', '1px solid red');
        valid = false;
    }
    else{
        $field.css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
    }

    return valid;
}
```

and `saveUser` like below.

```
saveUser: function (ev){
    var valid = true, that = this;

    this.$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
        valid = that.validates(null, $(this)); // validate input.
        if (!valid) return false; //break out from loop.
    });

    if (valid) {
        var userDeatils = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
        var user = new User({validate:true});
        user.save(userDeatils,{
            success: function(user){
                router.navigate('', {trigger:true});
            }
        });        
    }

    return false;
}
```